# I am looking for a Sci-Fi book set in the near future about a genetically engineered person

Tags: story-identification, genetic-engineering

This is a book set in the first person. In the beginning of the book there is a baby in a tube,  but then there's a fire and the baby escapes. Then you later learn that he was a genetically engineered baby. Also in this future the rich ride around in wheelchairs even though they don't need them. The main character can run up walls, has a virtually silent motorcycle (it emits a counter-tone to every sound the motorcycle makes), a sort of virtual reality training room, and an AI in his house. The house's security system consists of some spotlights as well. I think it has a sequal and you learn that the main character was originally genetically engineered from a perigrine falcon. Also the city the main character lives in is encircled by a wall and we learn that all cities are "islands" with similar walls around them.

Comment: That's all a bit jumbled together... I assume that the baby is either stated or implied to be the protagonist?

Comment: how long ago did you read it?

Comment: Yeah you kind of just assume that he's the protagonist. You pick up again with him when he's about 20 or so. I also read this when I was about 12 or so (in 2010) but I frequently read older books so I'm not sure if it would help.